# connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js - Failed to load resource

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is anybody else getting this for their Facebook Like buttons.  Tried on Chrome, Firefox, and IE and same thing.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please post your code.

Comment: happening again tonight it seems...

Comment: Same for me. Makes me feel better to know it wasn't me breaking something.

Answer (score 21):

For Google's sake, and because I've wasted much of my own time this way: whenever you see this error, it's worth checking if you've got AdBlock on.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my sanity. For me it was the DoNotTrackMe extension.

Comment: This is also happening with Avast antivirus. Thanks for the hint man.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/live_status/

As of 8:30pm 4/20/2012,

> **connect.facebook.net:** We are currently seeing issues with users connecting to connect.facebook.net. This is resulting in the JS SDK not loading correctly. We are aware of the problem and are working to resolve this.

Comment: thanks for the update, for those of us too lazy to look into it further right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

My company doesn't allow its employees to use facebook  due to which the sdk was not loaded in the chrome. I had to use vpn to make it work. Hope this helps